# No package autocomplete in asp.net core .csproj?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Previously, we used the project.json to setup our projects dependencies. The Asp.net Core team moved away from that and went back to using `.csproj`. However, when trying to type in the name of a package, it no longer auto-completes like it used to.

For instance, typing in the following line would show intellisense when I typed the `.` after `Microsoft`, providing me with the packages within that namespace.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

How do I get this functionality back?

Comment: Were you now able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still there in a Editor Extension called "[Project File Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ProjectFileTools)" which is a Microsoft Extension and I am pretty certain this should be installed by default, but on VS 15.3 Preview it didn't seem to be working (was installed, but I didn't had any other extensions there). Somewhere in between disabling/restarting/enabling it and/or installing the Web Essentials it started working again.

As for `Ctrl`+`.` doing a [reverse package search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net), it's there too but disabled by default:

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced (or hit Ctrl+Q and type "C# Adv" + Enter) and check "Suggest usings for types in NuGet packages".

If you already have a highlighted error before setting the changes you got to remove the piece of code and add it again before it gets recognized (read: it only applies for red-squiggles that happen after the change).

Answer (score 0):

This will probably depend on which IDE you are using.

If you're using Visual Studio then you'd right click on dependencies or csproj then click "Manage Nuget Packages".

[image]

This will open a view where you can search for packages and install them.

If you're using Visual Studio Code, there are couple of plugins that'll help you search and add packages you're looking for.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager

Lets you search package and add specific version.

Comment: I see, I really liked the namespace type intellisense rather than using the nuget package manager, but it can't be helped I guess. I'm using visual studio.

Comment: I also really liked the intelisense when adding packages.

Comment: I still have it on 2017 15.2 on both my Desktop, Work-Laptop and inside my VM, but not on 15.3 preview, probably one of the gazillion Extensions I have installed. `Ctrl`+`.` searching in NuGet packages can be enabled via options though

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: See my answer above, it's still there but seemed broken in my case on 15.3 Preview